# Getting all possible video file data using mediainfo in linux ( using C )

Tags: c, linux, video-processing, mediainfo

I need to extract all meta data along with play-length information from the video files in pure C .

I goggled and found MediaInfo Library but was not able to find any relevant c sample code .

Is there any other way to achieve this with / without MetaInfo ?

Or can somebody point me to a good sample code of MediaInfo in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffprobe which is part of ffmpeg can do a whole lot more.

ffprobe  without switches will give some common information 
It also has lot of switches of which you can use one at a time [exclusively]

- -show_format        show format/container info
- -show_streams       show streams info
- -show_packets       show packets info
- -show_frames        show frames info
- -show_data          show packets data

Try it out.